# Change TextField's Underline in Flutter

Tags: flutter, dart, textfield, underline

I'm working on an application using Flutter SDK. When I use a [`TextField`](https://docs.flutter.io/flutter/material/TextField-class.html) widget, and I focus it, the underline becomes blue. I need to change this color to red, how can I do it?

Screenshot of what I need to change. I want just the underline to change, **, not the label color.**

[image: Screenshot of what I need to change. (I want the underline to change, not the label color)]

Comment: Man I'm working on flutter. The one that you wrote is for native android.

Comment: Have a look at [this issue](https://github.com/flutter/flutter/issues/5989), might be of use if you want to change the color for all inputs. Also, might be usfull to share your aplication's theme code.

Comment: Btw you probably want to remove the java and perhaps android tags.

Comment: change the `hintColor` of your app theme, 
`return ThemeData.light().copyWith(
        hintColor: Colors.blueAccent,)`

Comment: This is most assuredly not a duplicate.  Android and Flutter are completely different technologies.

Answer (score 14, accepted):

While these other answers may somehow work, you should definitely **not** use it.
That's not the proper way to get a custom theme in Flutter.

A much more elegant solution is as followed :

```
final theme = Theme.of(context);

return new Theme(
  data: theme.copyWith(primaryColor: Colors.red),
  child: new TextField(
    decoration: new InputDecoration(
      labelText: "Hello",
      labelStyle: theme.textTheme.caption.copyWith(color: theme.primaryColor),
    ),
  ),
);
```

At the same time, if you just want to show an error (Red), use `errorText` of `InputDecoration` instead. It will automatically set the color to red.

Comment: Your answer definitely looks better, but it is a bit strange that you have to change the primary color to red and then change all the other styled items back to your real primary color.

Comment: Yeah I agree. Sadly you currently can't change the underline color without rewriting everything.

Comment: How can i set selected and default underline color.? Consider there are 4 textfields in the form if i am entering data in textfield1 so color of textfield1 and other textfields.

Comment: @RémiRousselet Can you bit help me to understand what exactly it requires to rewrite to change that underline color to something else. Because I've also stuck in the same kind of situation. Here is my post link -https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49600139/how-to-change-textfield-underline-color

Comment: For those who wasn't able to understand Remi's answer, a different answer helped me understand quite a bit: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49600139/how-to-change-textfield-underline-color

Answer (score 18):

You can also change its color by following ways.

1. Wrap your `TextField` in `Theme` and provide `accentColor`

   ```
   Theme(
     data: Theme.of(context).copyWith(accentColor: Colors.red),
     child: TextField(),
   )
   ```
2. Using `inputDecoration` property.

   ```
   TextField(
     decoration: InputDecoration(
       focusedBorder: UnderlineInputBorder(
         borderSide: BorderSide(color: Colors.red),
       ),
     ),
   )
   ```

Comment: damm its hard to find, but reading now underline input border its simple to memorize, thks OP

Answer (score 6):

I have used **InputDecoration.collapsed** to remove the divider and I am changing the color of the bottom border.

If you enter a name the bottom border color is **blue** and if you enter a number or other special characters then the bottom border color is **red**

[image: demo]

```
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';

void main() => runApp(new MyApp());

class MyApp extends StatelessWidget {
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return new MaterialApp(
      title: 'Flutter Demo',
      home: new MyHomePage(title: 'Flutter Demo Home Page'),
    );
  }
}

class MyHomePage extends StatefulWidget {
  MyHomePage({Key key, this.title}) : super(key: key);

  final String title;

  @override
  _MyHomePageState createState() => new _MyHomePageState();
}

class _MyHomePageState extends State<MyHomePage> {
  static const EdgeInsets _padding = const EdgeInsets.symmetric(horizontal: 20.0, vertical: 8.0);
  Color borderColor = Colors.blue;
  bool nameFlag = false;

  @override
  void initState() {
    super.initState();
  }

  void validateName(String value) {
    final RegExp nameExp = new RegExp(r'^[A-Za-z ]+$');
    if (!nameExp.hasMatch(value) || value.isEmpty)
      borderColor = Colors.red;
    else
      borderColor = Colors.blue;
  }

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return new Scaffold(
      appBar: new AppBar(
        title: new Text(widget.title),
      ),
      body: new Column(children: <Widget>[
        new Flexible(
          child: new Container(
            margin: _padding,
            padding: _padding,
            child: new TextField(
              decoration: new InputDecoration.collapsed(
                hintText: "Enter Name",
              ),
              onChanged: (s) {
                setState(() => validateName(s));
              },
            ),
            decoration: new BoxDecoration(
              color: Colors.white,
              border: new Border(
                bottom: new BorderSide(color: borderColor, style: BorderStyle.solid),
              ),
            ),
          ),
        )
      ]),
    );
  }
}
```

Let me know if this answers your question :)

Comment: Far too complex for what it is. Will be hard to maintain over the long run.

Comment: @Darky Actually It won't be hard to maintain.You can make a Custom widget as CustomTextFeild which will have all TextField Parameters as well as Some Custom One and use it everywhere.

Comment: Harder than just wrapping your `TextField` in a `Theme`. Especially in alpha where everything iterates  pretty quickly (a month ago `inputDecorationTheme` didn't even exists).

Comment: @Darky Oh yeah! You are right.... Missed your Answer above... Cool why I didn't thought of that :)

Answer (score 0):

I haven't tried it yet, but I had a look at the docs for you.

Looking at the [TextField](https://docs.flutter.io/flutter/material/TextField-class.html) class you can set an [InputDecoration](https://docs.flutter.io/flutter/material/InputDecoration-class.html), which in turn has an [InputBorder](https://docs.flutter.io/flutter/material/InputBorder-class.html). Setting that to an [UnderlineInputBorder](https://docs.flutter.io/flutter/material/UnderlineInputBorder-class.html) with your own [BorderSide](https://docs.flutter.io/flutter/painting/BorderSide-class.html) should do the trick I guess. You can set the color of the BorderSide.

You can also set an InputBorder in the global [InputDecorationTheme](https://docs.flutter.io/flutter/material/InputDecorationTheme-class.html) if you want all textfields to have the same style.

Comment: children: <Widget>[
                  objectTextField = new TextField(
                    decoration:  new InputDecoration(
                      border: new UnderlineInputBorder(borderSide: new BorderSide(color: Colors.redAccent)),
.......
I'm doing something like this, but it doesen't change anything.

Comment: Did you also try to set the inputdecorationtheme? It looks like it overrides the decoration color you set: (widget.decoration ?? const InputDecoration()) .applyDefaults(Theme.of(context).inputDecorationTheme);

Comment: It doesn't work.  For some obscure reasons, `TextField` internally overrides `borderSide` property of `inputDecorationTheme` and builds it from the primary color.

Comment: Setting `inputDecorationTheme` has worked for me. 
```
inputDecorationTheme: InputDecorationTheme(
            labelStyle: TextStyle(color: Colors.white),
            helperStyle: TextStyle(color: Colors.white),
            hintStyle: TextStyle(color: Colors.grey),
            focusedBorder: UnderlineInputBorder(
              borderSide: BorderSide(color: Colors.white),
            ) 
          ),
```