# How to change textField underline color?

Tags: dart, flutter

I'm new to both flutter & dart. Currently, using this in one of my personal projects.

[image]

In all of my form, the underline of textField is showing in blue color. I want to change that to some other color. The piece of code which I'm using is like...

```
new TextField(
  controller: this._emailController,
  decoration: new InputDecoration(
      hintText: "Enter your email",
      labelText: "Email",
      labelStyle: new TextStyle(
          color: const Color(0xFF424242)
      )
  ),

),
```

Can't able to understand how to achieve this.

Note: I know there is a similar question at here [Change TextField's Underline in Flutter](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48706884/change-textfields-underline-in-flutter). But, at there also it has not completely solved. Also, one more link which looks similar to mine at here [Changing EditText bottom line color with appcompat v7](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26574328/changing-edittext-bottom-line-color-with-appcompat-v7) but, that actually belong to Android development by using JAVA not DART(flutter) which I'm using for my android app development. So, please don't get confused about those links.

Comment: You can find same exact question here: [https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48706884/change-textfields-underline-in-flutter] and here [https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26574328/changing-edittext-bottom-line-color-with-appcompat-v7]

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Change TextField's Underline in Flutter](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48706884/change-textfields-underline-in-flutter)

Comment: I've already checked the first link. If you check that one then at there also this problem not completely solve. In the second link, that belongs to Android development by JAVA not flutter(DART). So basically, can't help me.

Answer (score 140, accepted):

** See update below or see [the answer by @GJJ2019](https://stackoverflow.com/a/52676093/2927226) **

The logical answer would be to use an InputBorder, particularly an [UnderlineInputDecorator](https://docs.flutter.io/flutter/material/UnderlineInputBorder-class.html), and pass it in to the inputdecorator as the border.  However, all this does is tell the InputDecorator whether is should use an underline or whatever else you specify.

The actual color is based on the theme - from the source:

```
Color _getActiveColor(ThemeData themeData) {
  if (isFocused) {
    switch (themeData.brightness) {
      case Brightness.dark:
        return themeData.accentColor;
      case Brightness.light:
        return themeData.primaryColor;
    }
  }
  return themeData.hintColor;
}
```

So to change the colour do something like this (or specify the theme for your entire application):

```
new Theme(
  data: new ThemeData(
    primaryColor: Colors.red,
    accentColor: Colors.orange,
    hintColor: Colors.green
  ),
  child: new TextField(
    decoration: new InputDecoration(
      hintText: "Enter your email",
      labelText: "Email",
      labelStyle: new TextStyle(color: const Color(0xFF424242)),
      border: new UnderlineInputBorder(
        borderSide: new BorderSide(
          color: Colors.red
        )
      )
    ),
  ),
),
```

UPDATE:

This is now possible to do in the way you'd *expect* it to work.

```dart
decoration: InputDecoration(        
  enabledBorder: UnderlineInputBorder(      
    borderSide: BorderSide(color: theColor),   
  ),  
  focusedBorder: UnderlineInputBorder(
    borderSide: BorderSide(color: theColor),
  ),
  border: UnderlineInputBorder(
    borderSide: BorderSide(color: theColor),
  ),
)
```

Comment: I tried that ```UnderlineInputDecorator``` but couldn't able make any solution for my problem.

Comment: Ah okay. When I get a chance I'll take a look and add a code example if noone else gets to it before me.

Comment: No Problem. Let me see what else I can do.

Comment: There, changed it to fix it. But as I mentioned briefly, you're probably better off specifying the theme for your entire application and then using that wherever you need to - that way you can change the entire theme if you want to =)

Comment: Oh man, I've got one answer from Gitter about wrapping everything inside a Theme & it worked now. Don't know all these in such great details. But, gradually learning. Thanks for your help.

Comment: So what purpose does `BorderSide` `color` serve?

Comment: This may have actually been fixed, see https://github.com/flutter/flutter/pull/19694.

Answer (score 231):

Just used -:

```
decoration: InputDecoration(        
              enabledBorder: UnderlineInputBorder(      
                      borderSide: BorderSide(color: Colors.cyan),   
                      ),  
              focusedBorder: UnderlineInputBorder(
                      borderSide: BorderSide(color: Colors.cyan),
                   ),  
             ),
```

it works for me :)

Comment: I Think U Should Also Try Material App Theme Settings. They Might Be Very Useful For Entire Color System.

Comment: @GJJ can ou give me any source to find a solution for that.

Comment: how can I apply `enabledBorder` on `InputDecoration.collapsed`

Answer (score 37):

To change the color for the **entire app**, use [`ThemeData`](https://api.flutter.dev/flutter/material/ThemeData-class.html)'s [`inputDecorationTheme`](https://api.flutter.dev/flutter/material/ThemeData/inputDecorationTheme.html) property.

- To use the color **only when the input is in focus** (i.e. clicked & ready to type):

  ```dart
  MaterialApp(
    ...
    theme: ThemeData(
      inputDecorationTheme: InputDecorationTheme(
        focusedBorder: UnderlineInputBorder(
          borderSide: BorderSide(color: Colors.red)
        ),
      )
    )
  )
  ```
- To **always** use the color (even when not in focus), set `enabledBorder` and `border` as well:

  ```dart
  MaterialApp(
    ...
    theme: ThemeData(
      inputDecorationTheme: InputDecorationTheme(
        focusedBorder: UnderlineInputBorder(
          borderSide: BorderSide(color: Colors.red)
        ),
        enabledBorder: UnderlineInputBorder(
          borderSide: BorderSide(color: Colors.red),
        ),
        border: UnderlineInputBorder(
          borderSide: BorderSide(color: Colors.red),
        ),
      )
    )
  )
  ```

Comment: your answer should be the best answer. Thank you

Answer (score 20):

```
    decoration: new InputDecoration(
              labelText: "Email",
              suffixIcon: Icon(Icons.email),
              labelStyle: TextStyle(color: Colors.red),
              enabledBorder: new UnderlineInputBorder(
                  borderSide: new BorderSide(color: Colors.red)
              )
        )
```

Answer (score 16):

By using InputDecoration, you can set underline color as per your requirement.

```
TextField(
            decoration: InputDecoration(
              hintText: "Enter your email",
              // [enabledBorder], displayed when [TextField, InputDecoration.enabled] is true
              enabledBorder: UnderlineInputBorder(
                borderSide: BorderSide(color: Colors.lightBlueAccent),
              ),
              //[focusedBorder], displayed when [TextField, InputDecorator.isFocused] is true
              focusedBorder: UnderlineInputBorder(
                borderSide: BorderSide(color: Colors.redAccent),
              ),
```

)
)

Answer (score 4):

need change three border.

```
  enabledBorder: OutlineInputBorder(
            borderSide: BorderSide(color: _type.color),
          ),
  focusedBorder: OutlineInputBorder(
        borderSide: BorderSide(color: _type.color),
  ),
  border:
    OutlineInputBorder(borderSide: BorderSide(color: _type.color)),
```

Comment: How do you do one border only (top, or left, or right or bottom)

Answer (score 0):

with  focusedBorder property in TextField can change underline color like :
    `focusedBorder: new UnderlineInputBorder( borderSide: new BorderSide(color: Colors.black), ),`

Answer (score 0):

```
@override
  ThemeData appBarTheme(BuildContext context) {
    return Theme.of(context).copyWith(
        primaryColor: Colors.transparent,
        appBarTheme: AppBarTheme(elevation: 0),
        inputDecorationTheme: InputDecorationTheme(
            border: UnderlineInputBorder(
                borderSide: BorderSide(style: BorderStyle.none, width: 0))));
  }
```