# Flutter change textfield underline Color

Tags: dart, flutter

I am trying to change the underline color of a textfield when it's inactive/not focused. I am not sure where to make this change, `InputDecorationTheme` is only changing the underline color for when it's selected. How do I achieve this?

```
inputDecorationTheme: new InputDecorationTheme(
          labelStyle: new  TextStyle(
              color: Colors.blue[200],
          ),
          hintStyle: new TextStyle(color: Colors.grey),
        ),
```

I am trying to change this color the textfield to a lighter grey when it's not selected/out of focus.

[image]

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Change TextField's Underline in Flutter](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48706884/change-textfields-underline-in-flutter)

Answer (score 8, accepted):

For those who might need to achieve something similar, change the `hintColor` in your `Theme` widget.

```
new Theme(
          data: new ThemeData(
              //this changes the colour
              hintColor: Colors.grey,
              inputDecorationTheme: new InputDecorationTheme(
                  labelStyle: new TextStyle(color: Colors.blue))));
```

Answer (score 5):

We can use **`InputDecoration`**

Try this way

```
 new TextFormField(
                        controller: passTextController,
                        decoration: new InputDecoration(
                            labelText: "Enter password",
                            enabledBorder: UnderlineInputBorder(
                              borderSide: BorderSide(color: Colors.grey),
                              //  when the TextFormField in unfocused 
                            ) ,
                            focusedBorder: UnderlineInputBorder(
                              borderSide: BorderSide(color: Colors.blue),
                              //  when the TextFormField in focused 
                            ) ,
                            border: UnderlineInputBorder(
                            )
                        ),
                        keyboardType: TextInputType.text,
                        obscureText: true,
                      ),
```

OUTPUT

[image]