# How to style the OutlineInputBorder of InputDecoration?

Tags: flutter

I am trying to style the border of `TextFormField`. I'm using it with an `OutlineInputBorder`. It by default takes an almost black color and on focus takes primary color. I tried to change color of the `BorderSide` but it ain't worked.

I also tried the workarounds mentioned at [Change TextField's Underline in Flutter](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48706884/change-textfields-underline-in-flutter) for `UnderlineInputBorder`, but nothing changes.

```
new TextFormField(
    decoration: new InputDecoration(
        labelText: "Email",
        contentPadding: new EdgeInsets.all(12.0),
        filled: true,
        border: new OutlineInputBorder(
            borderSide: new BorderSide(width: 2.0, color: Colors.white),
        )
    ),
),
```

Comment: You only want to change the border color?

Comment: Which color you want to set?

Comment: The border and label color.

Answer (score 2):

After digging deep, it seems like it's only configurable by ThemeData. So I simply added a Theme widget.

```
body: Theme(data: Theme.of(context).copyWith(
          primaryColor: Colors.white,
          accentColor: Colors.amber
      ), child: new TextFormField(
          decoration: new InputDecoration(
          labelText: "Email",
          contentPadding: new EdgeInsets.all(12.0),
      ),
),
```

#### input_decorator.dart#1440-1450

```
Color _getActiveColor(ThemeData themeData) {
    if (isFocused) {
      switch (themeData.brightness) {
        case Brightness.dark:
          return themeData.accentColor;
        case Brightness.light:
          return themeData.primaryColor;
      }
    }
    return themeData.hintColor;
  }
```