# Change TextField decoration onFocus in Flutter

Tags: dart, material-design, flutter, textfield, google-inbox

I would like to have a different `fillColor` for the `TextField` when it is in the focused state and a different one in the normal state. How to achieve this kind of behavior?

Similarly, is it possible to customize other styles as well based on the state of the `TextField`?

Edit:

I was aiming for a color transition something in lines of this for mobile with flutter.

[image: Searchbar transition]

Comment: assing custom focusManager, and than act based on change of focus.

Comment: or you can use ThemeData as mentioned here: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50622399/how-to-style-the-outlineinputborder-of-inputdecoration

Comment: @KrzysztofSkrzynecki I know that certain properties like outline border color are configurable via ThemeData as InputDecorator checks `isFocused` state. But that is not the case with properties like `fillColor`

Answer (score 17, accepted):

You can pass your own `FocusNode` object to your text field's `focusNode` attribute. `FocusNode` has `addListener` method in which you can call `setState` and thus re-render your widget.

```
class _ChangingColorsExampleState extends State<ChangingColorsPage> {
  FocusNode _focusNode;

  @override
  void dispose() {
    super.dispose();
    _focusNode.dispose();
  }

  @override
  void initState() {
    super.initState();
    _focusNode = new FocusNode();
    _focusNode.addListener(_onOnFocusNodeEvent);
  }

  _onOnFocusNodeEvent() {
    setState(() {
      // Re-renders
    });
  }

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return new Scaffold(
      appBar: new AppBar(
        backgroundColor: _getAppBarBackgroundColor(),
        title: new Text('Changing Colors'),
      ),
      body: new Container(
        color: _getContainerBackgroundColor(),
        padding: new EdgeInsets.all(40.0),
        child: new TextField(
          style: new TextStyle(color: _getInputTextColor()),
          focusNode: _focusNode,
        )
      ),
    );
  }

  Color _getContainerBackgroundColor() {
    return _focusNode.hasFocus ? Colors.blueGrey : Colors.white;
  }

  Color _getAppBarBackgroundColor() {
    return _focusNode.hasFocus ? Colors.green : Colors.red;
  }

  Color _getInputTextColor() {
    return _focusNode.hasFocus ? Colors.white : Colors.pink;
  }
}
```