# To change the UnderlineInputBorder properties in flutter

Tags: flutter, uitextfield

I have a `TextField()`, I want to change the Underlineinput **border color** and the **thickness** of it since it looks to the thickness. I have tried my level to change it but it is not at all working.

I have followed these links but nothing worked for me :

- [InputDecoration class in flutter](https://docs.flutter.io/flutter/material/InputDecoration-class.html)
- [InputBorder class in flutter](https://docs.flutter.io/flutter/material/InputBorder-class.html)
- [To change the color of the underline of textfield](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48706884/change-textfields-underline-in-flutter)

Tried so far is :

**CODE:**

```
decoration: InputDeocration(
   border: UnderlineInputBorder(
     borderSide: new BorderSide(
        color: Color.fromRGBO(173, 179, 191, 1),
        width: 0.5,
        style: BorderStyle.none
     )
   )
)
```

The only thing that works or changes the color here is for the `focussedBorder` and `enabledBorder`. I don't want this, so I'm looking forward to getting some good advice here.

It doesn't change anything. **What I want is :**

[image: Required Result]

**What I'm getting so far is this every time irrespective of the changes I make to the design :**

[image: Result]

Answer (score 14, accepted):

You can change the Underlineinput `border color` and the `thickness` Using the
**enabledBorder** and **focusedBorder** properties.

```
TextField(
 decoration: InputDecoration(
    enabledBorder: UnderlineInputBorder(borderSide: BorderSide(color: Colors.red,width: 2.0)),
    focusedBorder: UnderlineInputBorder(borderSide: BorderSide(color: Colors.teal,width: 5.0)),
    labelText: 'Your Email or Phone'
  )
)
```

Comment: It was `enabledBorder` which did the magic. I knew about it, but did not try it. Man!